# Invoke-command permissions

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I'm trying to execute remote command which echoes some text to a network share, but getting an error:

```
"PermissionDenied:[Add-Content] UnauthorizedAccessException".
```

The actual command is:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $MyWorkstation -ScriptBlock { Add-Content \\server\C$\Scripts\1.txt -Value "My Test"}
```

Tried also "Out-File" with the same result. NTFS permissions are OK.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Powershell, remote script access denied to network resources](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7794206/powershell-remote-script-access-denied-to-network-resources). [See also](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee309365%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Ok, but enabling WSManCredSSP Client on every computer is too much efforts for this task. Thanks.